# PHP beginner: getting available routes

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I'm a Rails developer and I just inherited a PHP project with no documentation. Is there a way I can find the hooks of the project? Like available routes and the like? And is there a `console` equivalent? Sorry for the broad question, really no idea where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: What framework does this project use?

Comment: issue `rake routes` from rails app root in command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP == Ruby**

**PHP =! Rails**

---

If you want to look at the routes for the PHP app, you'll have to look at what framework it uses. Only frameworks can provide a dynamic routing structure, as they capture the request & process on the backend

There are several "rail-like" frameworks in PHP, two of the top being:

- [**CakePHP**](http://cakephp.org/)

  Basically a clone of Rails. This is a good implementation of a framework, but is seriously tricky to get working. It has a command-line interface (like Rails), and handles routes in much the same way as Rails
- [**Zend**](http://zend.com)

  A pretty popular framework, especially for enterprise. Although I've not got huge experience with this framework, all my friends say it's very robust & relatively extensible

Another important factor to appreciate is PHP is not as eloquent as Ruby (with Rails). You'll have to do a LOT more wrestling with the data to get it working anywhere near to Rails' standards, and so it may be beneficial to actually look at porting to Rails

Comment: You should keep in mind, that without such framework any PHP-file can probably be called directly (urls containing .php) or the creator may have wrote their own URL-rewriting (maybe even in .htaccess). Sorry.

Comment: Yep, but that URL rewriting won't be dynamic. Rails' routing structure gives `domain.com/controller/action` - try writing that in `.htaccess` and have it dynamic for the entire system

Comment: I know routing in rails and if I look atproject like Wordpress and php.net they use .htaccess for dynamic routing (internaly rewriting to a handler php)

Comment: Yep you're right! But doesn't that mean Wordpress is acting like a framework? All a framework does is to structure your functions / methods, to allow for structured & efficient functionality. I agree you can handle routes dynamically, what I'm trying to explain is that in a framework, you can build the functionality / routes once & extend them as much as required. If you had to do it manually, you'd have to constantly tweak for every small change